# PowerShell Dobule Escape string with text "$__VAR__"

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

One of my scripts can be stripped down to the following code.

```
function Replace
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=0)]
        [string]
        $LiteralPath,

        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=1)]
        [string]
        $Expression,

        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=2)]
        [string]
        $Replacement
    )

    Get-Content $LiteralPath | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace $Expression, $Replacement } | Set-Content $LiteralPath + ".temp"
}
```

An example call to the script would be

```
Replace ".\MyFile.txt" "^#define abc.*" "#define abc 1"
```

I have run into a situation where the string I need to find and replace contains both dollar signs and underscores. The dollars signs must be escaped to prevent PowerShell from expanding the variable. One string contains a dollar sign followed by an underscore. This is causing an issue because PowerShell is not expanding the variable name but then is expanding the `$_` piping variable. How can I prevent PowerShell from expanding both variable name and piping token.

This is an example cal to the function with a string I need to escape.

```
Replace ".\MyFile.txt" "^\#\`$__LIBRARY_DIR\\prj.gpj" "`$__LIBRARY_DIR\prj.gpj"
```

In this example the line of text which reads `#$__LIBRARY_DIR\prj.gpj` is getting changed to `#$__LIBRARY_DIR\prj.gpj_LIBRARY_DIR\prj.gpj`. *I am looking for the text to be changed to `$__LIBRARY_DIR\prj.gpj`*

Notice the `$_`  is expanded which I do not want it to expand. I have tried adding more escape characters but that only causes them to appear in the file. How can the string be escaped to prevent `$_` from expanding?

Comment: `$_ -replace '^#',''` removes a leading `#` character from the string in `$_`.

Comment: have you tried using the builtin dotnet regex escape method? this ... `[regex]::Escape($YourStuffHere)` ... looks like it would work.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, Thanks for the suggestion I thought of that but it won't work. I need to be more specific about the line I want to update. By only searching for '^#' it finds and replaces text on many other lines. @Lee_Dailey, `[regex]::Escape()` seems like it is only applicable to the string I want to find. IE `"mystring" -replace [regex]::Escape("findexpression") "replacetext"`

Comment: That was just an example. You will need to use an appropriate regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In powershell, if you don't want variables to expand in your string, use 'single quotes' instead if "double quotes", that saves you the trouble of escaping the `$` sign with backticks.

Now in your case you have the additional challenge, that the `-replace` operator will also want to expand expressions that start with the `$` sign in the replacement string, regardless of the types of quotes that you use.

To tell `-replace` that you really want to see that `$` in your replacement string, you need to write `$$`:

```
'#$__LIBRARY_DIR\prj.gpj' -replace '^#\$__LIBRARY_DIR\\prj.gpj','$$__LIBRARY_DIR\prj.gpj'
```

**Note**: As others have correctly pointed out in the comments, if your task is to strip expressions from a leading `#`, you can do that in a more simple way:

```
'#$__LIBRARY_DIR\prj.gpj' -replace '^#'
```

Or alternatively with the good old "trim":

```
'#$__LIBRARY_DIR\prj.gpj'.TrimStart('#')
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. The trick is to escape `$` with `$$`. So I was able to use the following replacement string `"`$`$____LIBRARY_DIR\prj.gpj"`. I did however follow your recommendation and change the code to use `single quotes` instead of "double quotes". I knew both could be used in PowerShell but didn't know there was a difference in behavior.